# Fixed image overflows beyond div even though I specify overflow: hidden;

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
.trees-section {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 80vh;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden; 
}
.trees-image {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 80vh; 
    object-fit: cover;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div>
        <h1>MAIN EVENTS</h1>
    </div>
    <nav>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Gallery</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </nav>
</header>

<div class="trees-section">
    <img src="images/image3.png" alt="Creating Unforgettable Memories" class="trees-image">
    <div class="image-text">
        <p>Creating</p>
        <p>Unforgettable</p>
        <p>Memories</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="midsection-section">
    <img src="images/image4.png" class="midsection-image">
</div>

<div class="seats-section">
    <img src="images/image2.png" class="seats-image">
</div>

<div class="yellow-box"></div>
```

Here image3 is extending beyond the div it should be contained in. However, if I make .treess-image have position relative this is not an issue. How can I make the image fixed and be stopped from overflowing?
In its current state the image3 re appears at the bottom of the page and also between images if I make the window more narrow.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: I have converted your code into a snippet, but please add some sort of placeholder image of the size your originals were so we can debug this properly. Use something like `https://placehold.it/[width]x[height]`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to use `position: absolute;` instead of `position: fixed;` on that image (?). `position: fixed;`  always relates to the viewport, not the parent element.

Comment: But I still want the picture to be fixed to the viewport so that when I scroll it stays in the same place and other elements move up. I just also don't want it to be seen again after I scroll past it.